# change webView font-family via javaScript in android

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an **Epub Reader** application.
I need to add changing font tool in my application.
I have problem in my **JavaScript** side.

My app opens different Epub files and therefore I can not predict **Epub HTML,CSS files content**.

My function works for elements that doesn't have `font-family` attribute and it doesn't effect on elements could have  `font-family` attributes like **p**,**body** and **h** tags.

> **changeFont** function :

```js
    function changeFont(fontIndex) {
    
        var fontFamilyValues = ["aldhabi.ttf", "b_nazanin.TTF", "b_nazanin_outline.ttf", "iransanse_mobile.ttf"];
        var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
    
        var font=fontFamilyValues[fontIndex];
        var fontUrl="file:///android_asset/fonts/"+font;
        var fontName=font.substring(0,font.lastIndexOf('.'));
        newStyle.appendChild(document
          .createTextNode("@font-face{ font-family:"+fontName+";src: url("+fontUrl+");}"));
    
        document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
    
        newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*{font-family:"+fontName+";}"));
    
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having font-family attribute"? An inline style?

Comment: I think what you have to do is create a class in body tag injected by javascript and add the different posibilities in CSS: example body class="aldhabi" in css .aldhabi p {font-family:aldhabi}

Comment: No matter whether inline style or external style definition . All of elements fonts must change to user selected font .Imagine that user selected font is aldhabi.ttf  . If in epub css or html files one of defined elmentes has font-famly attributes. All elements font-family changes except that elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline style overrides `<style>` block (and style block overrides external css file). So you have to remove inline styles first:

```
$("*").css('font-family', '');
```

or using pure javascript:

```
 var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) 
 {    
     all[i].style.removeProperty('font-family');
 }
```

to force your new style over everything else you can also apply !important on your styles like this:

```
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*{font-family:"+fontName+" !important;}"));
```

Comment: As the Epubs are unknow for him, he have to make sure that elements styles are not set by javascript libraries on the fly too.

Comment: the * is **all** elements selector and should effect on all elements. You should inspect those elements which are not affected by * selector and check which style is overriding all other styles and where it comes from? @AlirezaBideli

Comment: * is all elements selector  thats true.
Your code will affect if there is inline style. I test your code again but in 2 ways , first inline style and second external style .You code works for inline styles while it has problem in extenal style way  .In other words if elements don't have inline style your code does not work

Comment: The code I wrote is just for removing font-family not for adding. So if you can not yet add font to some elements, another option is to add `!important` to your styles to force it over everything else. @AlirezaBideli  . I will add this suggestion to end of answer above.